# Access 1st element of array in aura:iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Can anybody tell me how can i access first element in an array in `aura:iteration`.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.ZenObjsnew}" var="zenobjsnew" indexVar="index">
<a href="{!v.linkpath1}">
 {!zenobjsnew.ZenLms_Name_del__c}
     </a>
</aura:iteration>
```

Here i want to access `{!zenobjsnew.ZenLms_Name_del__c}` first value.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So, do you have any problems with it?

Comment: with what?? @kurunve

Answer (score 7):

If you want the Nth value of a list, *and* you know which one you want (e.g. the first one), you can use the array syntax:

```
<a href="{!v.linkpath1}">
 {!v.ZenObjsnew[0].ZenLms_Name_del__c}
</a>
```

This would be preferable to using aura:iteration since you won't have to iterate over all items in the list, which could cause a serious performance problem.

---

Brief demo:

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:attribute type="Object[]" name="test" default="[ { a: 5 }, { b: 10 } ]" />
    "{!v.test[0].a}" should display the value 5.
</aura:application>
```

Comment: i am not getting any ouput

Comment: i think something is missing

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal Let me check. I know I've used this before.

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal I have added a generic copy-pastable demo. There might be a number of reasons why it's not working, but it's probably case sensitivity or no data where you expect it to be. This syntax definitely works.

Comment: Got it u have "{!v.ZenObjsnew[0].ZenLms_Name_del__c}" missed " ". Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

This will produce output for the first element only:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.ZenObjsnew}" var="item" indexVar="index">
    <aura:if isTrue="{! index == 0 }">
        <a href="{! v.linkpath1 }">
            {! item.ZenLms_Name_del__c }
        </a>
    </aura:if>
</aura:attribute>
```

Comment: That's one of my few complaints about aura:iteration... once you start iterating, you're going along for the ride. Need the first element but have a list of 10,000? Have fun waiting. apex:repeat and the other Visualforce repeats at least had a way to limit the number of items.

Comment: @sfdcfox You right. If we need only single data so why we waste our memory playing with loop.