# Access Nth value of a List without iteration in LWC?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

Similar to the answer [HERE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170987/access-1st-element-of-array-in-auraiteration) in aura components, I want to access an element of a multi-record List in a Lightning Web Component without iteration. Is this possible WITHOUT having to make a separate JS variable for each record returned? When I try similar syntax from the aura answer I get the following error:

```
Invalid expression {customMetadata[0].Field_Text__c} - LWC1038: Template expression doesn't allow computed property access
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <div>{customMetadata[0].Field_Text__c}</div> <!-- Error is here -->
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getScreenContent from '@salesforce/apex/ScreenContent.getScreenContent';

export default class ScreenContent extends LightningElement {
    screenNumber = 1;
    error;
    customMetadata = {};
    @wire(getScreenContent, { screenNumber: '$screenNumber' })
    content({data, error}){
        if(data){
            this.customMetadata = data;                
        }
        else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your intention. Do you want to return the first element in the list, or do you want to return a value depending on user input, or is your intention to apply some logic to the list and then return a value dependent on that?

Comment: @Kasper The intention is to have n records of custom metadata for n section of pages without the need to have n variables.

Comment: @PhilW I want to use a single LWC page as a flow screen component. I don't want to make a separate LWC for each node. The customer wants to define the body of the layout using custom metadata. So, I therefore have n-sections of page body for every node. Iteration isn't practical. Calling an element by index and name is. The lesser of two evils is just make a bunch of JS variables.

Comment: @PhilW - Except... It's possible to do in Aura, and not possible in LWC. Full stop. So some designer felt the need to apply it there, but not here. Your response reminds me of MongoDB stackexchange where they shout at the developer, "Well.. you shouldn't be doing that!!" Except, no, there's a Frankenstein backend that simply isn't allowing us to do that. Hey speaking of Frankenstein's maybe you can pass up the chain to fix Locker Service's crappy performance. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/295924/array-find-and-array-findindex-has-worst-performance-in-lwc-lightning-locker

Comment: @PhilW - "I cannot be sure since just what you need to do was not clearly explained." -- I explained this pretty clearly. The answer was marked before you ever commented. Simply put... the answer was no.

Comment: @PhilW - Hey I never shouted. I'm getting condescending stfu-like remarks. It's worth noting that anyone who read one document on LWC and the fact that its using native browser support in ES6 could've figured out performance was better. Why the sacrifices though? Saying "aura sucks and LWC is better" because of "simplifications" is still comparing apples to pumpkins.

Comment: Well, whoever PhilW was decided to pull his comments, but basically he was saying that I should be using "iteration" claiming that I was using the community to get around a "blocker" I created. I asked the question because maybe I was missing something that I feel should be there, but no I wasn't. They just didn't port it from Aura. Say thanks to PhilW here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/50252/phil-w

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexed expressions are simply not allowed. It is unknown if this will ever be allowed, perhaps because of a limitation of the runtime.

However, you could transform your array into an object:

```
this.customMetadata = Object.fromEntries(data.map((v,i)=>([`index${i}`,v]));
```

Which you could then access as:

```
{customMetadata.index0.Field_Text__c}
```

This assumes you want a hard-coded index instead of being able to choose dynamically (e.g. you still can't `{customMetadata[someIndexVar].Field_Text__c}`).

I could see this being useful for a very limited set of edge cases, but it may be what you're looking for.

Or, since we're talking about Custom Metadata, maybe you'd like to map it by name:

```
this.customMetadata = Object.fromEntries(data.map((v)=>([v.Name,v]));
```

This would give you the more ordinary:

```
{customMetadata.Default_Values.Field_Text__c}
```

Answer (score 2):

LWC does not support expressions.

What you can do is this.

```
<template>
    <div>{customMetadataFirstText}</div> <!-- Error is here -->
</template>
```

in your js this.

```
screenNumber = 1;
error;
customMetadata = {};
customMetadataFirstText;
@wire(getScreenContent, { screenNumber: '$screenNumber' })
content({data, error}){
    if(data){
        this.customMetadata = data;   
        this.customMetadataFirstText = this.customMetadata[0].Field_Text__c
    }
    else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

Also you have declared `customMetadata = {};` as object, so not sure how `[0]` will ever work. You need to declare `customMetadata = [];` if custommetadata is a list from server side.

Comment: Using "yet" is a bit off... there's no known plans to support expressions in LWC.

Comment: "so not sure how [0] will ever work." this.customMetadata = data; -- still works regardless of type initialization. It's JS so anything goes. This just guarantees the variable isn't initialized at null. In my question I said: "Is this possible WITHOUT having to make a separate JS variable for each record returned?"

Comment: @ESRouter So initialize it correctly if its an array like `[]`. For your question, no expressions are not supported in LWC, so you have to pick index or iterate.

Comment: @NagendraSingh - The point is moot. It's leftover code from the answer below. If you want to be "correct", it's in the eye of the beholder and not in the eye of the interpreter.